# Sistering a joist - bathroom floor

Tags: flooring, construction

I am repairing my bathroom subfloor which had a leak from the shower step that caused the floor to rot. So far I have demoed the shower floor and will demo the remaining bathroom floor and install completely new 5/8" plywood. It appears that not too much of the floor joist have any damage other than a single one which has visible water stains but no rotting. I want to sister another joist to this one just in case, I will do one as long as possible, end to end. My problem is as you can see from the image, the joist hanger  of the original joist will hinder the new joist from having a firm connection with the beam. What is the recommended solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you really feel you need to sister the joist all the way over to the beam, then I would 1) remove some more of the floor, 2) remove the existing single joist hangar and 3) replace it with a double joist hangar that will accommodate both the
existing and the sister joist.

Comment: Double joist hanger is the right answer, but... I can't tell how much crawl space you have under there; if you can get down there, you might not need to remove more floor. You might also consider trashing that joist entirely -- it doesn't look great from the pics.